# AT&T U-Verse Watch TV Online vs. Hulu

Tags: hulu

One of the features of AT&T U-Verse is that you can watch TV online at http://uverseonline.att.net/. When I visit this site, I noticed that most (all?) of the videos are hosted by [hulu](http://hulu.com).

I'm wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages of using one service over the other. For example, are there any shows available on one of the services and not the other? Do shows expire later on one of the services? Does one of them have less advertisements? Do shows arrive at one of the sites faster than the other?

The [FAQ](http://uverseonline.att.net/uv/faq) states:

> #### Why Should I login to U-verse Online?
>
> You can browse and watch thousands of full TV show episodes, movies, and clips without logging in to U-verse Online. However, by logging in with your ATT.net member ID, you can access additional features and functionality such as:
>
> - Viewing age restricted content (if you meet minimum age requirements)
> - Rating shows and movies
> - Creating and managing a personalized library
> - Sharing videos with friends via email
> - Viewing your U-verse guide and managing recordings on your DVR (if you have an AT&T U-verse account associated with your ATT.net Member ID)

I understand that part, I'm wondering about the video content on the site.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread from 2009](http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/ATT-Officially-Launches-Hulu-Clone-104403) says that at least one user had a better streaming experience on Hulu than on U-Verse online. Read the thread for further details.

According to [this article](http://www.telecompetitor.com/att-launches-video-portal-u-verse-online/), U-Verse Online offers "online streaming of television content and movies through content distribution partnerships with Hulu and *some movie studios*" (emphasis mine).

Digging around, I found a movie category called "[U-Verse Movies](http://uverseonline.att.net/uv/movies/studio/u-verse-movies)" which appears to contain some exclusive content, some of it pay-per-view, some of it free for anyone, and other content that appears to be available for U-Verse subscribers only.

So I can't tell yet how extensive it is, but there appears to be *some* content here that isn't straight from Hulu.